# Cassandra Recovering from "Table did not have any partition key columns in the schema tables"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have some table that is created via Spark Cassandra connector, the table created seem to be in a bad state as it cannot be queried or dropped, but I am able to run `desc` on it and it shows up for `desc tables`. However its columns don't show up in `system_schema.columns`. Causing the following error:

```
cqlsh:ams_staging> desc bcookie_sad_1540577971;

CREATE TABLE ams_staging.bcookie_sad_1540577971 (
    bcookie text PRIMARY KEY,
    sadinfo text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

cqlsh:ams_staging> drop table ams_staging.bcookie_sad_1540577971;
ServerError: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: Table ams_staging.bcookie_sad_1545270474 did not have any partition key columns in the schema tables
```

Full stack trace

```
ERROR [MigrationStage:1] 2018-12-21 01:58:59,386 CassandraDaemon.java:226 - Exception in thread Thread[MigrationStage:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Table ams_staging.bcookie_sad_1545270474 did not have any partition key columns in the schema tables
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:950) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:925) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:888) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesOnly(SchemaKeyspace.java:880) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:1277) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchemaAndAnnounceVersion(SchemaKeyspace.java:1256) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$1.runMayThrow(MigrationManager.java:534) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
```

The same error is causing some nodes to not be able to start. Also any other attempt to write to this keyspace via Spark Cassandra connector will fail with the same error. Attempting to truncate the table also does not work. I have also tried adding a partition_key column into `system_schema.columns` which also did not work.

I found https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13180 which seems to suggest the only way to recover is "restore from backup". Is there a way to simply drop these tables or have Cassandra forget about these tables?

Cassandra Version 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was unfortunately no way to recover. Dropping the keyspace is the only way.